# How to send broadcast after activity is created and loaded

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am creating a music app. I want to send a broadcast from main activity . Receiver is also in main activity. This broadcast access the Arraylist created and showed as fragments. Each fragment is in view pager. view pager is in main activity .

Now the problem is I am sending broadcast to access arraylist and reciever receives (sending broadcast from oncreate method of main class) it but the arraylist is still not created so no data is present and so it shows error.
Is there any way that i can send broadcast after the arraylist has been generated and fragments has been created?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements           SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{

private static int songEnded = 0;
View view;
Intent intent;
int a = 0, b = 0;
int x=0;
String[] path = Kaibee.getInstance().path;
ArrayList<collection> collections;
ArrayList<collection> songlist = Kaibee.getInstance().collections;
ArrayList<collection> fav = fav_collection.getInstance().fav;
TextView bsongname,starttime,endtime;
collectionAdapter collectionadapter=new favorite().mAdapter;
ImageView bsongimage;
int seekProgress;
ImageButton greenplay,favourite;
RelativeLayout songinfo, rl;
LinearLayout bottomll;
View bottomSheet;
FloatingActionButton fb;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
ImageView bnext,bprev,playlist;
favlistdb mydb;
bottomsheetdb bdb;
playerservice ps;
favorite f=new favorite();
private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private int seekMax;
private Toolbar toolbar;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent serviceIntent) {
        updateUI(serviceIntent);
    }
};
private IntentFilter bfilter = new IntentFilter("songclick");
private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("songc");
//   private IntentFilter pfilter = new IntentFilter("bottomsheetbutton");
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(bBroadcastReceiver, bfilter);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
    ps= new playerservice();

    bdb = new bottomsheetdb(this);
 Cursor result=bdb.getdata();
    if (result != null) {
        int pos=0;
        String listname = null;
        if (result.moveToFirst() ) {

            do{
            listname =  result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(bottomsheetdb.COL_2)) ;
                pos =(result.getInt(result.getColumnIndex(String.valueOf(bottomsheetdb.COL_3))));
                System.out.println("bottomsheet data "+listname+" "+pos);
                Intent minten = new Intent("songclick");
                minten.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
                minten.putExtra("position",pos);
                minten.putExtra("pause","play");
                minten.putExtra("collect",listname);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(minten);
                ps.setupHandler();

            }while(result.moveToNext());

        }
    }
    else{bottomSheet.setVisibility(View.GONE);}




    // Create an adapter that knows which fragment should be shown on each page
    category_adapter adapter = new category_adapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set the adapter onto the view pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    // Connect the tab layout with the view pager. This will
    //   1. Update the tab layout when the view pager is swiped
    //   2. Update the view pager when a tab is selected
    //   3. Set the tab layout's tab names with the view pager's adapter's titles
    //      by calling onPageTitle()
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    //setting data inside bottom sheet
    try {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, playerservice.class);

        // --- set up seekbar intent for broadcasting new position to service ---
        intent = new Intent("seek_update");
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}



public BroadcastReceiver bBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
        x=0;
        String ss=i.getExtras().getString("collect");
        if(ss.equals("song_list_fragment")){collections=Kaibee.getInstance().collections;}
        else if(ss.equals("album")){collections=song_album_fetch.getInstance().albumsong;}
        else if(ss.equals("artist")){collections=artist_songs_fetch.getInstance().artistsong;}
        else if(ss.equals("genres")){collections=genres_songs_fetch.getInstance().genresong;
        }
        else{collections=fav_collection.getInstance().fav;}
        a = i.getExtras().getInt("position");
        collectionadapter=new collectionAdapter(getApplicationContext(),fav);
    //    collectionadapter=f.mAdapter;
        String s = i.getExtras().getString("pause");
        String play = "play", pause = "pause";
        if (s.equals(play)) {
            greenplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled);
            fb.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow);
        } else {
            greenplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline);
            fb.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        }

        bottomSheet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
};






/**
 * Dispatch onResume() to fragments.  Note that for better inter-operation
 * with older versions of the platform, at the point of this call the
 * fragments attached to the activity are <em>not</em> resumed.  This means
 * that in some cases the previous state may still be saved, not allowing
 * fragment transactions that modify the state.  To correctly interact
 * with fragments in their proper state, you should instead override
 * {@link #onResumeFragments()}.
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(bBroadcastReceiver);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

}

Comment: post your some code.

Comment: Why are you using broadcast receiver for same activity?

Comment: there is no reason to use broadcast to call from same class.

Answer (score 0):

A way to register the broadcast receiver:

```
private MyReceiver mMyReceiver;

private class mMyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context mContext;
    public mMyReceiver(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(YOUR_ACTION)) {
            // get data from intent
        }
    }
}

private void registerReceiver() {
    if (mMyReceiver== null) {
        mMyReceiver= new MyReceiver(this);
    }

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(YOUR_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(mMyReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

In onCreate and onDestroy:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // others
    registerReceiver();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   if(mMyReceiver != null){
        unregisterReceiver(mMyReceiver );
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Note: Please consider other ways if it is the same activity

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to achieve your target...

```
 registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("INTENT_NAME"));



 private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
};
```

---------------- ***Send Using*** ---------------------------------

```
Intent intent = new Intent("INTENT_NAME");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you send a broadcast, the call to the receiver is posted at the end of the main thread's work queue.  If you register the receiver and send the broadcast in `onCreate`, the receiver will not be called until sometime after `onCreate` returns.  Other activity lifecycle methods may already be in the queue, so they would also have to run and return before your receiver is called.

Comment: i Dont know why but i have placed my code after viewpager that loads the fragments that contains arraylist , but it still calls the broadcast first and then try to load fragments